# paging in java swing with jtable and database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am new to java and I am working on Jtable with  database.i fill up my jtable by data from database ,now I need to  use paging and I don't know how to implement this in my code,i used DbUtils to fill up the jtable,every think is ok but the problem is that i don't know how to use pagination, thank you in advance for any sharing of information and help

```
public class FenetrePers extends JFrame  {
    private JTextField rechNomField;
    private JTextField rechPrenField;
    private JTextField rechemailField;
    private JTextField rechtelephField;
    private JButton btnNewButton_2;
    AjoutPers ajpers;
    
    
    Connection cnx =null;
    PreparedStatement prepared=null;
    ResultSet resultat=null;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton editButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    
    public FenetrePers() {
        cnx=ConnectionSql.ConnexionDB();
        
        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("       Gestion du personnel");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 23, 181, 21);
        getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        rechNomField = new JTextField();
        rechNomField.setBounds(27, 84, 175, 32);
        getContentPane().add(rechNomField);
        rechNomField.setColumns(10);
        
        rechPrenField = new JTextField();
        rechPrenField.setBounds(298, 84, 163, 32);
        getContentPane().add(rechPrenField);
        rechPrenField.setColumns(10);
        
        rechemailField = new JTextField();
        rechemailField.setBounds(587, 84, 163, 32);
        getContentPane().add(rechemailField);
        rechemailField.setColumns(10);
        
        rechtelephField = new JTextField();
        rechtelephField.setBounds(844, 84, 157, 32);
        getContentPane().add(rechtelephField);
        rechtelephField.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton FindButton = new JButton("find");
        FindButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
                try {
                    UpdateTableSearch();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
        });
        FindButton.setBounds(1034, 89, 66, 27);
        getContentPane().add(FindButton);
        
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("reset");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
                String nomS=rechNomField.getText().toString();  
                String prenomS=rechPrenField.getText().toString();  
                String emailS=rechemailField.getText().toString();  
                String telephS=rechtelephField.getText().toString();
                if(!nomS.equals("")|| !prenomS.equals("")|| !emailS.equals("")||!telephS.equals("")) {
                rechNomField.setText("");
                rechPrenField.setText("");
                rechemailField.setText("");
                rechtelephField.setText("");
                UpdateTable();
                
                
            }}
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(1110, 89, 66, 27);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
        
        btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Ajouter personnel");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
             ajpers =   new AjoutPers(FenetrePers.this);
            UpdateTable();
            
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(1034, 24, 142, 32);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);
        
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(27, 150, 985, 308);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        
        table = new JTable();
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                
            
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

Comment: What do you mean by pagination?  Do you want to retrieve 20 rows at a time?  50 rows at a time?  All the rows with a scroll bar?

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. Don't use setBounds. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 3) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc sorry i mean paging ,how to use a paging?

Comment: Why are you asking essentially the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044057/paging-in-java-swing-with-jtable-and-database-ask

Comment: This is the third version of this questions I've seen today. One of the others is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033496/paging-in-java-swing-with-jtable-and-database   Sorry, it is only the second.

Comment: You still haven't defined what paging means to you and why you need to use it.

Comment: @camkir I want to use it to load 20 or 30 staff from a database to each page in jtable

Comment: Two things.  Your database of choice has to support LIMIT.  You use LIMIT to read the 20 or 30 row slice from the database.  Your GUI has to create ActionListeners for the JButtons to get the next or previous 20 or 30 rows from the database and display them in the JTable.

Comment: I need an example,i m new in java and i don't found any solution

Comment: This in not about Java, it is about the SQL query. What keywords did you use in your search. I used "sql limit" and found: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-limit-clause/. So every time you do a query you reset the TableModel with the new data. It will be up to your code to track the "offset" you want to start reading rows of data from.